# WSS-3.0 Web Parts using 4.0 framework

Tags: .net-4.0, wss-3.0, web-parts

Is it possible to develop Web Parts using the 4.0 framework and use them in WSS 3.0?  I've searched all over the place and can't find anyone else asking this question which makes me think the answer is an obvious "no".

Answer (score 1):

WSS 3.0 seems not to work with Net Framework 4.0. You can see this happening just changing any SharePoint site to use Net Framework 4.0 instead of Net Framework 2.0 or 3.0. You'll see that the site won't work showing an "Unexpected error".